# Coalesce identically named columns of data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, coalesce

I have a data frame with identically named columns. I need to coalesce (in the sense of `dplyr::coalesce`) the values in these columns. Hence if I start with `DuplicateAgeColumns`, then I should end up with `CoalescedAgeColumns`, where:

```r
DuplicateAgeColumns <- data.frame(Condition = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                                  Age = c(18, 19, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                                  Age = c(NA, NA, 20, 21, NA, NA),
                                  Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 22, 23),
                                  check.names = FALSE)

CoalescedAgeColumns <- data.frame(Condition = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3), 
                                  Age = c(18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23))
```

I have tried `dplyr::coalesce(DuplicateAgeColumns$Age)`, but that doesn't seem to coalesce anything.

My actual data frame has multiple sets of identically named columns. (Imagine that there are multiple `Age` columns *and* multiple `Score` columns.) So, ideally, the answer would handle all such sets of columns simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
DuplicateAgeColumns %>%
 setNames(make.unique(names(.))) %>%
 transmute(Condition, Age = invoke(coalesce, pick(starts_with("Age"))))
```

-output

```
  Condition Age
1         1  18
2         1  19
3         2  20
4         2  21
5         3  22
6         3  23
```

---

If there are many duplicate categories, use `split.default` to split into a list

```
cbind(df1[-1], data.frame(lapply(split.default(df1[-1], 
  sub("\\.\\d+", "", names(df1)[-1])), \(x) do.call(coalesce, x))))
```

Comment: ^ This is closest to what I was hoping for. A slightly shorter version ```DuplicateAgeColumns %>% setNames(make.unique(names(.))) %>% transmute(Age = invoke(coalesce, pick(starts_with("Age"))))``` (without ```Condition, ```) works even better than what I thought I wanted (because it doesn't have the condition name attached to it and, therefore, allows me to just append the coalesced column to the dataset by prepending ```DuplicateAgeColumns$AgeCoalesced <- ```).

Answer (score 0):

Scrappy but works. I will be relieved to see a more elegant solution.

```
orig_names <- colnames(DuplicateAgeColumns)
dupe_col <- data.frame(table(orig_names))
dupe_col <- dupe_cols[dupe_col$Freq > 1,]
dupe_col_pos <- which(orig_names %in% dupe_col$Var1)

library(dplyr)
coacross <- function(...) { coalesce(!!!across(...))}
DuplicateAgeColumns <- DuplicateAgeColumns %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  mutate(Age2 = coacross(dupe_col_pos))
colnames(DuplicateAgeColumns) = c(orig_names, "Age_coalesced")
```

Result

```
  Condition Age Age Age Age_coalesced
1         1  18  NA  NA            18
2         1  19  NA  NA            19
3         2  NA  20  NA            20
4         2  NA  21  NA            21
5         3  NA  NA  22            22
6         3  NA  NA  23            23
```

Answer (score 0):

With this solution I could deal with NA values (all columns have NA) and also address multiple variables with duplicate columns.

```
DuplicateAgeColumns <- data.frame(Condition = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3),
                                  Age = c(18, 19, NA, NA, NA, NA),
                                  Age = c(NA, NA, 20, 21, NA, NA),
                                  Age = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 22, 23),
                                  Score = c(10, NA, 1, NA, NA, NA),
                                  Score = c(NA, 5, NA, 10, NA, 9),
                                  Score = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), check.names = FALSE)
```

Get the names of duplicate columns:

```
nm <- names(DuplicateAgeColumns)
duplicateNames <- unique(nm[duplicated(nm)])
```

Create a row coalesce function that works with a data.frame or matrix of with the same vector type.

```
# assumes same type of vector
myRowCoalesce <- function(x) {
  xx <- t(as.matrix(x))
  unlist(lapply(1:ncol(xx), function(y) {
    isNA <- is.na(xx[,y])
    if(all(isNA)) {
      return(NA)
    } else {
      unname(xx[,y][min(which(!isNA))])
    }
  }))
}
```

Get the values with the new function and a vector of duplicated names (in this case Age and Score). Note I use a test to get a vector of TRUE/FALSE to select the columns with the same name since the names are duplicated and cannot be used to select. Also we need to name the resulting list from lapply so we can create a new data.frame later.

```
dedupedValues <- lapply(duplicateNames, function(x) {
  myRowCoalesce(DuplicateAgeColumns[,names(DuplicateAgeColumns)==x])
})

names(dedupedValues) <- duplicateNames
```

Put together the non duplicated columns with the new data.frame of deduplicated columns.

```
notdupColumns <- DuplicateAgeColumns[!(names(DuplicateAgeColumns) %in% duplicateNames)]

dedupedColumns <- do.call("data.frame", list(dedupedValues))

cbind(notdupColumns, dedupedColumns)
```